# Not able to upload artifact in JFrog using maven-release-plugin from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, release, maven-release-plugin

I am using Jenkins to build my project. I am using "maven-release-plugin" and "release plugin", both plugins has been installed in Jenkins. We are getting below error message while building my project, could anybody please help me on this to fix this issue. We would like to upload the artifact in JFrog instead of Git. We want to autoincrement the version of artifact.

Error:

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project Test: The scm url is invalid.

Command: `mvn -B clean release:prepare release:perform`

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId></groupId>
    <artifactId></artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name></name>
    <url></url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:cvs:https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-copra-team-ipat-dev-maven-local/</connection>
        <url>https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:cvs:https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-copra-team-ipat-dev-maven-local/</developerConnection>
    </scm>
        
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
                <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<connection>scm:cvs:https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-copra-team-ipat-dev-maven-local/</connection>
<developerConnection>scm:cvs:https://na.artifactory.swg-devops.com/artifactory/gbs-copra-team-ipat-dev-maven-local/</developerConnection>
```

these won't work. You can see [here](https://maven.apache.org/scm/cvs.html) what is supported by cvs:

> The general format for a CVS SCM URL is
>
> ```
> scm:cvs<delimiter><method>
> ```
>
> The following methods are supported:
>
> - ext, connecting to a server using an external rsh program
> - local, connecting to the local file system
> - lserver, connecting to a local server
> - pserver, connecting to a password-authenticating server
> - sspi, secure authentication (less supported by clients and servers, may require using native implementation, for more details see "How to
>   choose the CVS provider implementation")
> - sserver, SSL connection method for CVS (only if cvs_native is used i.e. using -Dmaven.scm.provider.cvs.implementation=cvs_native with
>   Maven)

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but cvs over https won't work. Are you sure you're really using cvs?